# Serving an image from Node.js to React (how does the frontend part work?)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, web-development-server

I know there are a lot of similar posts out there yet after reading as many as I could find I am still left with questions.

I have a site set up with a node server running on port 5000 and React running on port 3000. I am using multer to upload user selected images from the front end and save them in the file system on the node backend side, which works perfectly fine.

My trouble lies in trying to get those same images and serve them back to the react front end to render on page. I have tried using express.static() to serve the images as several folks talk about doing but when I do so I don't know how to actually access those images from the front end, I couldn't find anyone talking about that part. When trying to access by the relative path from the front end I recieve net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200

My very rudimentary backend code:

```
    router.get("/retrieve/:id", async(req,res) => {
        const pathname = path.join(__dirname,"../userProjects/project_ted/photos/test.jpg")
        app.use(express.static(pathname));
        res.send(200);}
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here with having my front and back end running on two different ports and attempting to send a picture from the node side to the react side with express?
2. If I am not then what does the front end code look like to render a picture served from express?

To be clear I don't want to download the photo, I want to display it on the page.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all images upload in single folder(uploads)
and uploads folder is in root directory of your project.

In server.js/main.js file of your project use middlewares
```js
app.use('/image', express.static('uploads'))
```
Get in browser(react) like this below:
just type in browser: http://locahost:5000/image/imageName.jpg

Comment: ^ This results in the net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin 200

Comment: Solved the err with this bit of code :

```app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));```

Answer (score 0):

First, the `app.use()` is misplaced. It shouldn't be in a route callback.

As far as I understand you're trying to send a test image to all requests. If so, you can use Express' [`sendFile` method](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) for that:

```js
router.get("/retrieve/:id", (req, res) => {
  const pathname = path.join(__dirname,"../userProjects/project_ted/photos/test.jpg")
  res.sendFile(pathname);
});
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to just send a test image and then have the calling front end code display the image on page. This is great, but I do not know how to acess the image and display it within a page on the front end. When I send it, should it then be accessible by res.data from the call I am making to the get function ? Or is it somethign else entirely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To access the image directly from the fronted do

```
<img src={'http://localhost:5000/userProjects/project_ted/photos/test.jpg'} alt="" />
```

This worked for me.